# Determine sequence of most used words in Excel data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to determine sequence of most occurring word in a excel data set. Eg.

```
     A              B                 C            D
Joyce Bremner   Lewis Chapman   Claire Harper   
Lesley Brown    Brian Clough    Natalie Hassan  
Emma Cartwright Janet Coldwell  Gillian Hedley  
Lewis Chapman   Sheena Doig     Lesley Brown    
Brian Clough    Karen German    Emma Cartwright 
Janet Coldwell  James Gledhill  Lewis Chapman   
Sheena Doig     Maggie Gowan    Brian Clough
```

Which name is the most occurring and then 2nd most occurring word and so on.

I have found solution for determining the most concurring word in sequence when you take only one column into consideration but struggling to combine for multiple column. Below is the formula used:

Enter this array formula in C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A10,MODE(MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)+{0,0})),"")
```

Enter this array formula in C3 and copy down until you get blanks:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,MODE(IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,A$2:A$10)=0,MATCH(A$2:A$10,A$2:A$10,0)+{0,0}))),"")
```

Comment: Nash: Why is the data structured like this?  Is it possible to just put it all in one column?  If that is the case, then a pivot table is a good option.

Comment: Sam This is only sample, i have data with over half a million lines and more then 50 columns. So if I can find a solution for small data set, i will be able to apply it to big. Additionally excel won't be able to pull that that data in one line due to line limitation.

Comment: Nash - showing a better sample would be helpful then.  I still think pivot table is best answer but I'll edit my answer when you post the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the single column and pivot are a feasible idea...

- Put all the names in one column
- Format as table (my pref.)
- Select "Summarize as pivot table"
- Add "Name" field to Rows and Values

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for writing this however putting all the columns into one column is a big challenge as I have more then 50 columns and each have half million line. Thats my i want to find a solution via a formula like the one I used. Pivot is great but not for such big data set. Although appreciate your help.